# Is there a way to pass a variable in schematron?

Tags: xml, xslt, xsd, xslt-2.0, schematron

I want to use a variable to represent my schematron assertion and use it in my validation message. For example:

```
        <rule context="//Profile/User[@name]">
            <assert test="@name = ../business/@owner">User: '----' doesn't exist as a business owner. </assert>
        </rule>
```

The '----' being whatever the name of the user was. Is there a way to use variables in schematron?

Answer (score 3):

You can use `value-of` to retrieve the value of a variable or an XPath:

```
    <rule context="//Profile/User[@name]">
        <assert test="@name = ../business/@owner">
          User: <value-of select="@name"/> doesn't exist as a business owner.
        </assert>
    </rule>
```

If you wish to introduce a variable, use `let`:

```
    <rule context="//Profile/User[@name]">
        <let name="userName" value="@name"/>
        <assert test="@name = ../business/@owner">
          User: <value-of select="$userName"/> doesn't exist as a business owner.
        </assert>
    </rule>
```

Comment: This actually just prints the memory address: User:  [PSValueOf@0x361c294e: select=@name], doesn't exist as a business owner.

Comment: Works with [Schematron "skeleton" - XSLT implementation](https://github.com/Schematron/schematron).  You seem to be using Philip Helger's implementation.  Not sure why that should be any different.